# lme4 fails to build on Ubuntu (Precise Pangolin) : RcppEigen.h: No such file

Tags: r, ubuntu, lme4

I have a problem to install lme4 under Ubuntu (Precise Pengolin). I get the following error message:

```
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
Loading required package: Matrix
** installing vignettes
   ‘Comparisons.Rnw’ 
   ‘Design-issues.Rnw’ 
   ‘Intro2Matrix.Rnw’ 
   ‘Introduction.Rnw’ 
   ‘sparseModels.Rnw’ 
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (Matrix)
* installing *source* package ‘lme4’ ...
** Paket ‘lme4’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"  -DNDEBUG -DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c external.cpp -o external.o
In file included from external.cpp:7:0:
predModule.h:12:23: fatal error: RcppEigen.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [external.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘lme4’
```

My session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is RcppEigen installed?

Comment: Thanks, no. This is the problem it seems. It I need to update R to install RcppEigen. > install.packages("RcppEigen", dep=T)
Installing package into ‘/home/mark/lib/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warnmeldung:
package ‘RcppEigen’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)  AND R CMD INSTALL RcppEigen_0.3.1.2.3.tar.tar.gz   Error: this is R Version 3.0.1, Paket 'RcppEigen' needs R >= 3.0.2

Comment: I'm surprised that trying to install `lme4` didn't complain about this missing dependency in the first place. Did you install via `R CMD INSTALL`, or via `install.packages("lme4",dep=FALSE)` ... ?  You can (and are encouraged to) post your comment as an answer ...

Comment: I cleared up anything in my .Rprofile and suddenly it did compile.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue under ubuntu 14.04 and solved it by installing **r-base-dev** package:

sudo apt-get install r-base-dev

Answer (score 1):

Yes... I have just fixed it like this:

```
remove.packages("RcppEigen")
install.packages("lme4")
```

It's also possible that you might have to delete the folder

```
./R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/00LOCK-RcppEigen/
```